# Create PDFReader from String or InputStream

Tags: java, itext7

Below is my code to create PDF from input `String` or `byte[]` 
This input is working with `iText5`. When I pass input to `PdfReader` in `iText5` it was able to create PdfReader object.

Case 1:

```
    byte[] bytesDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(bytesDecoded.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
```

Case 2:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(IOUtils.toInputStream(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
```

Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.io.IOException: PDF header not found.
    at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.getHeaderOffset(PdfTokenizer.java:223)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.getOffsetTokeniser(PdfReader.java:1018)
```

Not working in `iText7`

Comment: I don't understand why people give downvote and not even understand the question or adding any comment. Is my question not understandable? or is something shouldn't ask here.

Comment: Where does your String come from? Don't use String at all, use plain byte[] array, avoid unnecessary conversions.

Comment: @AlexeySubach, I have upstream (Oracle BIP) system which gives encoded String.

Comment: Ok, and are you able somehow successfully save that PDF from String to a file in your local filesystem so that it is opened correctly in any PDF reader? If you are, then use the same method to create a `PdfReader`. If you are not, you will have to figure it out first because then the issue is not about iText at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I have done. Sharing it as may be useful in future.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytesDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(src.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesDecoded);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inStream);
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, pdfos, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest method to create a PdfReader from a Byte[] or a String.

```
byte[] template;

PdfReader templatePdf = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(new MemoryStream(template).ToArray()),new ReaderProperties());
```